# How to put align a link right side in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, what I want is to align the logout button right hand side and three modules (contact us, about epm and modules) at center, so how can I do this with the help of bootstrap.Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.jsp" style="color:purple;cursor: auto" id="wel">Welcome Admin</span></a>
    </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="about_epm.jsp">About EPM</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Modules <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
            <li><a href="#">Employer Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employee Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Client Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Project Details</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

    <li>
        <a onClick="logout();" class="navbar-brand pull-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" id="icon"> Logout</span>  
        </a>
    </li>

    </ul>   
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This HTML and your current CSS in a JSfiddle.net demo would be useful.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/ would probably be better if you are using Bootstrap

Comment: I am not familiar with JSfiddle, so can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To right align the logout object, you can use bootstrap's `navbar-right` class.

To center align the other links you can use the following CSS:

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 { text-align:center; }
.centered-navbar { display:inline-block; float:none; vertical-align:top; }
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.jsp" style="color:purple;cursor: auto" id="wel">Welcome Admin</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav centered-navbar">
        <li class="active"><a href="about_epm.jsp">About EPM</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Modules <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
            <li><a href="#">Employer Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employee Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Client Section</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Project Details</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a onclick="logout();">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" id="icon"> Logout</span>  
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/ddmUGfX0PI

Comment: @user3222665 If you follow the bootply link, you can see it in action. If it is not working on your site, then perhaps there is other code interfering.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you Marcelo , but now one other problem arises.

Comment: @user3222665 Okay, if this answers the question, go ahead and mark it as an answer. What is the problem that came up?

Comment: @user3222665 I see you edited your original code. I've updated my solution to match your new code.

Comment: Thanks alot Marcelo , you did it. :)